# Linux software/application deployment tool like docker?

Tags: linux, deployment, docker

Docker is great. It allows me to quickly run a web application without having to configure my OS to become a host. I use an OpenVZ VPS so I cannot use docker. OpenVZ is a container itself, ideally I would have the OpenVZ template preconfigured I want to use hosted on the VPS, but this is not possible, I have to configure it myself. So I am wondering if there is a tool that can serve as a 1 click installer (zero configuration) for any application by grabbing from a repo (like docker) or preconfiguring/installing once so that it can be deployed without all the steps of configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You may be interested in [OpenSUSE build server](https://build.opensuse.org/). For example to deploy ownCloud, just follow [this page](https://software.opensuse.org/download.html?project=isv:ownCloud:community&package=owncloud).

Answer (score 0):

I suspect there no such integrated framework like docker.
Try to use Ansible (or other management system) to automate deployment.